# how to deal with "challenge" in http request

Tags: python, http, post

So I'm trying to log in via http request, just for learning purpose

```
import requests

payload = {"cvalue": "", "password": ""}
url = 'https://auth.roblox.com/v2/login'

header = {"X-Csrf-Token": ""}

response = requests.post(url, headers=header, data=payload)

print(response.content)
print()
```

well It work, sorta, but I have this problem when trying to get the content

```
"message":"Challenge is required to authorize the request"}]}
```

If I have to take a guess it has something to do with the funcaptcha

I want to log to the website

Comment: Maybe this is helpful to get into the topic of challenges in requests? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication